# How can nitrogen be both inert and bond with everything in periodic table?

Tags: noble-gases

Aren't below statements from [this](https://www.gordonengland.co.uk/elements/n.htm) link contradicting each other?

> - Nitrogen bonds to almost all the elements in the periodic table    except the first three noble gases, helium, neon, and argon
> - Nitrogen gas is mostly used as an inert atmosphere whenever the    oxygen in the air would pose a fire, explosion, or oxidising problems

How can one element be both inert and bond with everything at the same time? Aren't inertness and bonding mutually exclusive?

Comment: Are you aware that the noble gases mentioned are also inert in the first place?

Comment: ...[cont] If you see the [Wiki page of Argon compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon_compounds), there exist cations like $\ce{ArN2+, Ar(N2)2^+, ArN2O+, ArNH+}$ etc. which has been detected albeit unstable. There also exists polyatomic van der Waals argon-nitrogen molecules. Also, [a high pressure Van der Waals solid, $\ce{(N2)6Ne7}$ has been detected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_compounds).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nitrogen as an atom can be bound to any other atom of the periodic table. But nitrogen as a molecule is something else. It is $\ce{N2}$ and the two atoms are strongly bound in the molecule. It is even extremely difficult to separate the two atoms from the molecule $\ce{N2}$, because $\ce{N2}$ contains a triple bond : there are three covalences between the two atoms. That is why $\ce{N2}$ is nearly inert. A huge amount of energy is needed to break these three bonds. And it is usually impossible to do it in a lab at ordinary temperatures. Some plants (beans, peas) are able to do it and to metabolize $\ce{N2}$ by a somewhat mysterious process.

Comment: Ah ok so the first point refers to the atom $N$, and the second point refers to the molecule $N_2$. Got this XD Thank you so much!

Comment: For chemical vapor deposition techniques one usually uses ammonia as a nitrogen source.

Comment: @Maurice Inert relates with kinetics. Why bond energy which is a thermodynamic factor relates with kinetics?